# two user controls in the same page using jquery do not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, user-controls

I have two same user control in Mizan.aspx.I want to use autocomplete

txtHesapKodu in belHesapPlani(it is usercontrol).When i write anything in the

first user control textbox,it works and everything is fine.On the other

hand,While I write in the second user control textbox,it is not work and do not

run GetHesapKodu function that is used.

```
      $(document).ready(function () {
          SearchText();
          //$('txtHesapKodu').keyup(function () {
          //    SearchText();
          //});
      });

      function SearchText() {
          $("#txtHesapKodu").autocomplete({
              source: function (request, response) {
                  //alert("user controldeyizx");
            //      alert(document.getElementById('txtHesapKodu').value.uniqueID);
                  $.ajax({
                      type: "POST",
                      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                      url: "../../jqueryTEST.asmx/GetHesapKodu",
                      //url: "belHesapPlani.ascx/GetHesapKodu",
                      data: "{'hesapKodu':'" + document.getElementById('txtHesapKodu').value + "'}",
                      dataType: "json",
                      success: function (data) {
                          response(data.d);
                      },
                      error: function (result) {
                          alert("No Match");
                      }
                  });
              }
          });
      }
```

Mizan.aspx

```
            <td>
                <uc12:belHesapPlani runat="server" ID="belHesapPlani1" ClientIDMode="AutoID" Enabled="true" />
            </td>
        </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>
                    <uc12:belHesapPlani runat="server" ID="belHesapPlani2" ClientIDMode="AutoID" Enabled="true" />
                </td>
```

```
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod]
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
public List<string> GetHesapKodu(string hesapKodu)
{
    DataTable dt = new MH_HESAP_PLANI().GetAllByHesapNameIdKurum(1, "HESAP_KODU", hesapKodu, null);

    List<string> strList = new List<string>();
    foreach (DataRow item in dt.Rows)
    {
        strList.Add(item["NAME"].ToString());
    }

    return strList;
}
```

Comment: When i write in second textbox,I get the first usercontrol textbox value.

Answer (score 0):

You are filtering for `#txtHesapKodu` in `SearchText()` but please keep in mind that the `#` filters for an ID and IDs are unique across the whole site. So you cannot have an element with the same ID in 2 different user controls. Use the name attribute instead and filter (`Name=[txtHesapKodu]`) instead.

Comment: When i write in second textbox,I get the first usercontrol textbox value.

Comment: @ugurkabalak ...because you are filtering for an ID and as i always stated an ID is unique across the whole site, you **cannot** have the same ID twice. Add a name attribute instead of an id attribute to make it work. If you don't know how to do that then post some code of your user control.

Comment: <tr>
        <td style="height: 30px">
            <asp:Label ID="lblHesapKodu" runat="server"  Text="Hesap Kodu" align="left" Width="86px"></asp:Label>
        </td>
        <td style="height: 24px">
        
              <asp:TextBox ID="txtHesapKodu"    runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" ></asp:TextBox>
        
       
        </td>

Comment: function SearchText() {
              $("input[name*='txtHesapKodu']").autocomplete({
                  source: function (request, response) {
                      alert(document.getElementById("<%=txtHesapKodu.ClientID %>").value);
                      alert(document.getElementById('txtHesapKodu').value);
                      alert($(this).attr('txtHesapKodu').value);
                  
                  
                  }
              });

Comment: @ugurkabalak Please add these code lines to your original answer as the comment are not designed for posting huge amount of code. Anyway, please post the code of your custom controls that is rendered to the browser. This must be something like `<input type="text"...`